# MarketingCloudSdk.getRegistrationManager () method is not bringing the messages

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

I'm following the Journey Builder for Android Android SDK (Rich Push Inbox) tutorial https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/rich-push/rich-push-inbox.html
To get the cloudpage's message, but the count methods and the getCloudPageMessages itself is not returning anything. Even after several successful messages.

Have you been through this or do you have an idea of what it might be?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Even after several successful messages"?  Are you specifically crafting a CloudPage Message in the Marketing Cloud Push UI?  Have you verified whether or not your device is in the delivery list?  Have you enabled logging on the SDK and can you see the messages getting downloaded to your device?

Comment: Sorry, bill.
I had the test with alert and alert + page. Being that the getCloudPageMessages method only picks up from sending CloudPage (which is stored in the inbox).
Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You'll be glad to know that a change is coming soon by which the alert+inbox (new naming) will result in a notification message as well as the message being put into your inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, only the CloudPage Message will result in a message in your CloudPage Inbox.  An upcoming release (very soon) will change this functionality such that an InboxMessage as well as the Alert+InboxMessage will both show up in your application's inbox.

Comment: Great news Bill, I'll keep up with the update. Thank you.